# react native dynamic flatlist set condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, native

I want to render a flatlist, and there are some condition based on the items, like button styles. However, it does not work in the button style like this. How can i fix it. Thanks for your patience. It really troubles me.

```
 this.state = {
          data: [
            {
              Type: 'Finished',
            },
          ],
        };
      <FlatList
            data={this.state.data}
            // extraData={this.state}
            keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
             <Button
             style={ ***{item.type} === 'Finished' ? styles.sth : styles.sthElse*** }>
            }
       />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line:

```
style={ ***{item.type} === 'Finished' ? styles.sth : styles.sthElse*** }
```

should be this:

```
style={ item.type === 'Finished' ? styles.sth : styles.sthElse }
```

Comment: Was OP not just highlighting which part of his code that didn't work?

Comment: Sure but they also had to remove the additional curly brackets around item.type. the style property is already being executed. By putting item.type in curly brackets, they're creating an object. item.type is not an object.

Answer (score 0):

In your state you have `Type: 'Finished'` but in your ternary you look for `item.type`. Best to double check case sensitive characters.